# I want to write an R function get the corresponding index of a pair of data

Tags: r

I have a dataset which has 2 variables and want to write an R function as follows: If I input one pair (one row) arbitrarily from the dataset into this function, I want to extract the corresponding index of the dataset through the function.

I used,

```
data = rnorm2d(10,rho = 0.4)
x = c(data[10,1],data[10,2])
print(match(x, data))
```

generated dataset is:

```
       [,1]       [,2]


[1,] -0.1792099  1.3007178
[2,]  0.3280193  0.6615251
[3,] -0.4390389 -1.9611801
[4,] -1.3096660 -0.9117184
[5,]  0.5165317 -0.3229271
[6,] -1.0963584 -1.1492360
[7,]  0.3447118  0.5357070
[8,] -0.8919166  0.4934032
[9,] -0.2199690  0.5788579
[10,] -0.9864628  0.6880458
```

But this gave me an output as follows:

```
[1] 10 20
```

Comment: match apparently converts your matrix into a vector. For this vector the output is correct. This at least explains the output.

Comment: Yes. But this will be a problem when there are equal values in the dataset. So I am trying to match both values together.

Comment: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/how-to-find-a-row-index-in-a-matrix-or-a-data-frame-td3058696.html